# Slash command response not parse correctly

Tags: php, api, command, slash, slack

My question is related to Slack's Slash commands.

I am trying to echo response back to invoking channel.

e.g I have integerated a test command like

```
/test hello
```

and I want response as:

```
Hello
Wold
```

but I am currently getting it as (in my slack channel):

```
{"text":"hello\nworld"}
```

This is my PHP code:

```
$payload = '{"text":"hello\nworld"}';
echo $payload;
```

**Note** I don't want to just echo like this:

```
echo "hello\nworld";
```

Thanks in advance :)

Maybe useful in giving answer:-

Sample wrong response actual:

[image]

Slack slash command API url:
**https://api.slack.com/slash-commands**

Comment: So if your payload is json and you get in your slack channel the same json you printed, then maybe you just have to echo what you want to show in your channel? I mean, no one gets special flavour.

Comment: Yes that is possible but actually i need to print other things also that the api allows, but i cannot print those like, emoji icon with the text, then it will only show text emoji but not actually shows an emoji.

Comment: you need to change the line: $payload = '{"text":"hello\nworld"}'; to be: $payload = 'payload={"text":"hello\nworld"}';

Answer (score 0):

If you had carefully read the docs (which you linked), you would have noticed that it says:

> NOTE: If you are responding with JSON instead of plain text, the content-type header of the response must match the disposition of your content, application/json.

It looks like you're just outputting JSON without sending the correct Content-Type header, so Slack thinks it's plain text and displays your JSON as plain text.

Also, consider using `json_encode` instead of manually writing JSON.